# How to prevent dist folder which gets generated from being checked in .net Angular project? Or not generate in project?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have a .net angular project and building it generates a 'dist' folder with compiled code - how can i prevent this from being checked into source safe? or maybe make it not generate it in project?

Comment: [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html). If you have the ClientApp/dist structure, you should simply delete the dist folder and it shouldn't be regenerated. [source](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1654)

Comment: Add a line `dist/` into the `.gitignore` file